# I try to install node in my Mac but I have issue

Tags: node.js

I tried to install node , I use brewhome website and first I use link in terminal step by step base on YouTube ,I installed node npm and so on but doesn' work I tried to Remove all node from my Mac manually and with terminal 
then I tried to install again I took same step it seems the node install but I as soon as write npm init , its said doesn't have directory

==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.7.0: 4,663 files, 53.2MB
==> Caveats
==> icu4c
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

==> node
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
Saras-MacBook-Pro:sara saramoshggoo$ npm init
env: node: No such file or directory
Saras-MacBook-Pro:sara saramoshggoo$

I am super new with using Mac laptop and also react language is anybody can help me  I am so frustrated

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and [how to install it for Mac](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/).

**Note:** It is hard to find out the issue with the provided information and some of the similar questions already exist.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's try to uninstall Node completely from your system. Most likely things may have gone awry when you tried to install and uninstall multiple times.

**Uninstallation**

Follow these steps for uninstallation of Node on Mac,

`brew uninstall node`

And then to be absolutely sure execute these,

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}`

**Installation**

After uninstallation let's start afresh and try to install Node.
The most standard way of installation is directly from Node website,

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Simply download the package from above and run it. It will take care of things for you.

However, the most preferred way of installation is to use `nvm`. This gives you the benefit of installing multiple versions and switching as you please. For example, you can install both LTS and Current versions and develop with whatever you need for your project and experiment.
Refer this for ``nvm``` usage and installation,

https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/